# Город и городище

Tags: значение-слов, однокоренные-слова

В археологии по отношению к найденным древним поселениям часто употребляют слово "городище". Однако сложно назвать городищем, например, руины Афинского Акрополя или Баальбек. Впрочем, это храмы - не совсем удачный пример. Ну, скажем, Херсонес или Помпеи.
О них мы можем сказать только "древний город" или "руины древнего города".
Так что же такое на самом деле городище и чем оно отличается от города?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ГОРОДИЩЕ, -а; м. Увелич.
   к Город (1 зн.).
2. ГОРОДИЩЕ, -а; ср.
   Д***ревнее укрепленное поселение; город (2 зн.). //
   Место, сохранившее следы древнего укрепленного поселения.***

   > ***Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
   > Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
   > Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.***